# c++ Como manipular y trabajar con caracteres UTF-8

Tags: c++, dev-c++, utf-8, txt

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo .txt codificado en UTF-8 y debo hacer validaciones en el mismo.

Estoy trabajando en Windows 10 aun que necesito que la solución funcione de igual manera en Linux.
Trabajo con Dev c++ 6.3, Compilador TDM-GCC 9.2.0 64-bit y estoy compilando con GNU C++11

de momento estoy leyendo el siguiente archivo .txt:

```
Inicio
D1
Biatlón
S1
255
E1
Esprint 7,5 km (M); 100; 200
E2
Persecucion 10 km (M); 100; 200
ff
```

Este es mi código:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <locale>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include <windows.h>
#define CP_UTF8 65001 
#define CP_UTF32 12000 

#include <codecvt>

using std::cout;

std::wstring utf8_to_ws(std::string const&);

int main(){
    
    std::ifstream file;
    std::string text;

    if (!SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)) {
        std::cerr << "error: UTF-8 codigo.\n";
        return 1;
    } 

    file.open("entradaDisciplinas.txt");
    
    int linea = 0;
    
    if (file.fail()){
        
        cout<<"No se pudo abrir el archivo. \n";
        
        exit(1);
        
    }
    
    while(std::getline(file,text)){ 
        
        if(linea == 2){

            std::cout<<text[5]<<"\n";
            auto a = utf8_to_ws(text);
            std::wcout<<a<<"\n";
            
        }
        
        std::cout<<text<<"\n";
        
        linea++;
        
    }
    
    cout<<"\n";
    
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}



std::wstring utf8_to_ws(std::string const& utf8)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> cnv;
    std::wstring s = cnv.from_bytes(utf8);
    if(cnv.converted() < utf8.size())
        throw std::runtime_error("incomplete conversion");
    return s;
}
```

Y estoy recibiendo lo siguiente por consola:

```
Inicio
D1

Biatln
Biatlón
S1
255
E1
Esprint 7,5 km (M); 100; 200
E2
Persecucion 10 km (M); 100; 200
ff
```

si imprimo el archivo en pantalla si recibo el carácter "ó" pero por separado no, necesito interactuar con dicho carácter para hacer validaciones, necesito comprobar que en esa line ano vengan numeros ni caracteres especiales: "!,?,:" etc. ademas necesito guardar ese nombre en una cadena y poder interactuar con ella y mostrar resultados por consola.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si quieres algo que funcione tanto en Linux como en Windows, usa funciones multiplataforma como las que se encuentran en STL. Por ejemplo `system("Pause");` ejecuta un comando propio del sistema y puede que no esté disponible en otro. En su lugar podrías usar `cin.get()`.

Comment: @Mateo Gracias por la recomendación, lo tendré en cuenta para cuando solucione el problema del caracter y haga pruebas en linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes mezclar el `std::cout` con el `std::wcout`. Debes convertir las palabras entre `UTF-8` y `UTF-32/UCS-2`.

Algo como así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <locale>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include <windows.h>
#define CP_UTF8 65001
#define CP_UTF32 12000

#include <codecvt>

using std::cout;

std::wstring utf8_to_ws(std::string const&);
std::string ws_to_utf8(std::wstring const& s);

int main(){

    std::ifstream file;
    std::string text;

    if (!SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)) {
        std::cerr << "error: UTF-8 codigo.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    file.open("entradaDisciplinas.txt");

    int linea = 0;

    if (file.fail()){

        cout<<"No se pudo abrir el archivo. \n";

        exit(1);

    }

    while(std::getline(file,text)){

        if(linea == 2){

            // No puedes elegir un byte del UTF-8 porque la letra
            // puede contener más de uno bytes
            // std::cout<<text[5]<<"\n";

            // así que, convértalo a UTF-32/UCS-2
            std::wstring wide_text = utf8_to_ws(text);

            // debes elegir la letra desde el UTF-32/UCS-2
            wchar_t wide_letra = wide_text[5];

            // ahora debes cambiar la letra a UTF-8 otra vez
            std::wstring wide_string(1, wide_letra);
            std::string utf8_string = ws_to_utf8(wide_string);

            // Solo ahora puedes imprimir la letra elegida
            std::cout << utf8_string << '\n';

        }

        std::cout<<text<<"\n";

        linea++;

    }

    cout<<"\n";

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}



std::wstring utf8_to_ws(std::string const& utf8)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> cnv;
    std::wstring s = cnv.from_bytes(utf8);
    if(cnv.converted() < utf8.size())
        throw std::runtime_error("incomplete conversion");
    return s;
}

std::string ws_to_utf8(std::wstring const& s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> cnv;
    std::string utf8 = cnv.to_bytes(s);
    if(cnv.converted() < s.size())
        throw std::runtime_error("incomplete conversion");
    return utf8;
}
```

No puedo probarlo en `Windows` pero en `Linux` se imprima:

```
Inicio
D1
ó
Biatlón
S1
255
E1
Esprint 7,5 km (M); 100; 200
E2
Persecucion 10 km (M); 100; 200
ff
```

Comment: el código funciona bien para imprimir el carácter individualmente en pantalla, pero no logro hacer la validación del carácter con esto, y ya entiendo que estoy teniendo un mal enfoque del problema, existe alguna forma de comparar `utf8_string`  con   `ó` ?, o con su codificación, por ejemplo comparar `utf8_string` con `\xC3\xB3` que es el código Utf8 para `ó`, o alguna otra solución? muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @ramej Sí, se puede hacer algo así `if(utf8_string == "\xC3\xB3") ...` o `if(utf8_string == "ó") ...`.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!, en mi caso lo hice de la siguiente forma: `if(utf8_string == u8"ó")` hay que especificar el u8 antes, gracias nuevamente.